# How to calculate the <fo:region-before /> height?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

In my pdf document, I want some data to repeat on all pages, so I put them in `<fo:region-before/>`. It leads to the height of the region is not fixed. I want to calculate the height of this region to place data of `<fo:region-body/>` at appropriate position, but I don't know how to do that? Here is my code:

```
<#assign imageBorderWidth=0.4/>
<#assign logoHeight=0.5/>
<#assign regionAfterBlockHeight=0.22/>
<#assign regionAfterHeight=regionAfterBlockHeight * 4/>

<#setting locale="en_US">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="ArialUni, ArialUniBold, ArialUniItalic" font-size="10pt">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="letter-portrait" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in"
                               margin-top="0" margin-bottom="0" margin-left="0in" margin-right="0in">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="5in" margin-bottom="${regionAfterHeight}in"
                            margin-left="${imageBorderWidth}in" margin-right="${imageBorderWidth}in" background-color="yellow"/>
            <fo:region-before extent="2in" />
            <fo:region-after extent="${regionAfterHeight}in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>

    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="letter-portrait" id="mainSequence">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="0" left="0">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:external-graphic src="${backgroundLocation.getLocation()}" content-height="11in" content-width="8.5in" scaling="non-uniform"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
            <#--Header Hóa đơn GTGT, logo, mẫu số-->
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%">
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="0.5in 0.5in 0in 0.5in" text-align="center" width="2.5in">
                            <fo:block>
                                <#if logoLocation?has_content>
                                    <fo:external-graphic src="${logoLocation.getLocation()}" content-width="2in" content-height="${logoHeight}in" scaling="non-uniform"/>
                                <#else >
                                    <fo:leader />
                                </#if>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="center" width="3.5in" padding-top="${imageBorderWidth}in" display-align="center ">
                            <fo:block-container height="0.34in">
                                <fo:block font-size="14pt" font-family="ArialUniBold" text-align="center">
                                    HÓA ĐƠN GIÁ TRỊ GIA TĂNG
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block-container height="0.27in">
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:inline font-style="italic">(Bản thể hiện của hóa đơn điện tử)</fo:inline>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                            <fo:block-container height="0.27in">
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:inline font-style="italic">Ngày tháng năm</fo:inline>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="center" width="2in" padding-top="${imageBorderWidth}in" display-align="center">
                            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" >
                                <fo:table-column column-width="30%"/>
                                <fo:table-column column-width="60%"/>
                                <fo:table-body>
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                                            <fo:block-container height="0.27in">
                                                <fo:block><fo:inline>Form no:</fo:inline></fo:block>
                                            </fo:block-container>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                                            <fo:block-container height="0.27in">
                                                <fo:block><fo:inline>01GTKT0/001</fo:inline></fo:block>
                                            </fo:block-container>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                                            <fo:block-container height="0.27in">
                                                <fo:block><fo:inline>Sign:</fo:inline></fo:block>
                                            </fo:block-container>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                                            <fo:block-container height="0.27in">
                                                <fo:block><fo:inline>AB/21E</fo:inline></fo:block>
                                            </fo:block-container>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                    <fo:table-row>
                                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                                            <fo:block-container height="0.27in">
                                                <fo:block><fo:inline>No:</fo:inline></fo:block>
                                            </fo:block-container>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left">
                                            <fo:block-container height="0.27in">
                                                <fo:block><fo:inline>000001</fo:inline></fo:block>
                                            </fo:block-container>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </fo:table-body>
                            </fo:table>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
            <fo:block border-bottom-width="1.5pt" margin="0 ${imageBorderWidth}in 0 ${imageBorderWidth}in " border-bottom-style="solid" margin-top="3mm" border-bottom-color="#b7b7b7" />
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" margin-top="0.1in" font-size="10pt">
                <fo:table-column column-width="80%"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="20%"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="${imageBorderWidth}in">
                            <fo:block font-size="15pt" font-family="ArialUniBold" line-height="1.4"><fo:inline>CÔNG TY TNHH QUẢN LÝ NỢ VÀ KHAI THÁC TÀI SẢN NGÂN HÀNG TMCP BẮC Á - CHI NHÁNH THÀNH PHỐ HỒ CHÍ MINH</fo:inline></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="center" number-rows-spanned="5" display-align="before" padding-right="${imageBorderWidth}in">
                            <fo:block>
                                <#assign qrContentWidth=(8.5*0.2) - imageBorderWidth/>
                                <fo:external-graphic src="${qrCodeImgLocation.getLocation()}" content-width="${qrContentWidth}in" content-height="scale-to-fit" scaling="uniform"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="${imageBorderWidth}in">
                            <fo:block line-height="1.8"><fo:inline>Taxcode: 0101243150-999</fo:inline></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="${imageBorderWidth}in">
                            <fo:block line-height="1.8">
                                <fo:table inline-progression-dimension="auto" table-layout="auto">
                                    <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="45pt" />
                                    <fo:table-column column-number="2"/>
                                    <fo:table-body>
                                        <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding="0">
                                                <fo:block>Address:</fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding="0">
                                                <fo:block>Số 36A Phan Đăng Lưu, Phường 05, Quận Phú Nhuận, Thành phố Hồ Chí Minh, Việt Nam</fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </fo:table-row>
                                    </fo:table-body>
                                </fo:table>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="${imageBorderWidth}in">
                            <fo:block line-height="1.8"><fo:inline>Phone: 028.38229812</fo:inline></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="${imageBorderWidth}in">
                            <fo:block line-height="1.8"><fo:inline>Bank Account:</fo:inline></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
            <fo:block border-bottom-width="1.5pt" margin="0 ${imageBorderWidth}in 0 ${imageBorderWidth}in " border-bottom-style="solid" margin-top="1mm" border-bottom-color="#b7b7b7" />
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after" font-size="9pt" >
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" >
                <fo:table-column column-width="90%"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="10%"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" padding-left="${imageBorderWidth}in">
                            <fo:block-container height="${regionAfterBlockHeight}in"><fo:block text-align="left">Tra cứu tại Website: https://www.meinvoice.vn/tra-cuu - Mã tra cứu hóa đơn:</fo:block></fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell/>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell >
                            <fo:block-container height="${regionAfterBlockHeight}in"><fo:block text-align="center">(Cần kiểm tra, đối chiếu khi lập, giao, nhận hóa đơn)</fo:block></fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell/>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block-container height="${regionAfterBlockHeight}in"><fo:block text-align="center">Phát hành bởi phần mềm MISA meInvoice - Công ty Cổ phần MISA (www.misa.com.vn) - MST: 0101243150</fo:block></fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-right="${imageBorderWidth}in">
                            <fo:block-container height="${regionAfterBlockHeight}in">
                                <fo:block>
                                    <fo:block text-align="right"><fo:page-number/>/<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="endContent"/></fo:block>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:block-container>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" >
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            <fo:block>aaaaa</fo:block>
            .......  
            <fo:block id="endContent">aaaaa</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

And my result , the **yellow area** is `<fo:region-body/>` and the **red rectangle** is `<fo:region-before/>`, I want the **yellow area** is continue immediately after the **red rectangle** and the **red rectangle** repeated on all pages
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplistic answer would be to put everything in an `fo:table`, with the current page header in the `fo:table-header` that repeats on every page.

A more complicated solution would be to use the XSLT extensions from the Print and Page Layout Community Group at https://github.com/pplcg/XSLTExtensions to run the formatter during the XSLT transformation to get an area tree for the header content so that you can work out exactly how much height it needs. However, the `<#assign` and other markup makes me think that you might not have much access to the XSLT processor and might not be able to configure it to use the extension.

Comment: thank you Tony, I've put it in `fo:table-header` and the issue is solved